# Cannot get data from request.get_json(force=True)

Tags: python, flask

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

url = 'http://localhost:5000/api'

dat = np.genfromtxt('/home/panos/Manti_Milk/BigData/50_0_50_3.5_3-3.dat')
d1 = dat[:,0]

data = {"w0": d1[0], "w1": d1[1], "w2": d1[2], "w3": d1[3], "w4": d1[4],
          "w5": d1[5], "w6": d1[6], "w7": d1[7], "w8": d1[8], "w9": d1[9], "w10": d1[10],
          "w11": d1[11], "w12": d1[12], "w13": d1[13], "w14": d1[14], "w15": d1[15]}

jsondata = json.dumps(data, indent=4)


r = request.post(url, json = jsondata)
```

```
@app.route('/api',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():

    jsondata = request.get_json(force=True)
    dummy = json.loads(jsondata)    
    arr = np.fromiter(dummy.values(), dtype=float).reshape(16,1)

    return {"data": arr}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

It returns <kbd>Bad Request
Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</kbd>

When setting force=False, returns "Null"

Any Help?

I have read several questoins/answers where it should work. But this is not the case!

Comment: You JSON is invalid, check using https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Many thanks, I corrected using json.dumps, and the tool validated it! However, still returns the same "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: def predict():
    jsondata = request.get_json(force=True)
    dummy = json.loads(jsondata) 
    arr = np.fromiter(dummy.values(), dtype=float)

The same after the above edit... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to decode json data after `request.get_json()`, it is already the Python `dict`. So the line `dummy = json.loads(jsondata)` is unnecessary.

```
@app.route('/api',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    jsondata = request.get_json(force=True)
    arr = np.fromiter(jsondata.values(), dtype=float)
```

**EDIT:**

First file - server.py:

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def predict():
    jsondata = request.get_json(force=True)
    arr = np.fromiter(jsondata.values(), dtype=float).reshape(16, 1)
    print(arr)  # do whatever you want here
    return "1"


app.run(debug=True)
```

Second file - client.py:

```
import requests
import numpy as np

dat = np.genfromtxt('data.dat')
d1 = dat[:, 0]

data = {"w0": d1[0], "w1": d1[1], "w2": d1[2], "w3": d1[3], "w4": d1[4],
          "w5": d1[5], "w6": d1[6], "w7": d1[7], "w8": d1[8], "w9": d1[9], "w10": d1[10],
          "w11": d1[11], "w12": d1[12], "w13": d1[13], "w14": d1[14], "w15": d1[15]}

requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api", json=data)
```

Then execute them separately (from different console tabs):

At first, start the server in [1] tab:

```
$ python server.py

 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
```

And after that run request from client in another [2] tab:

```
$ python client.py
```

Then you will see desired output in server tab [1]:

```
[[2297.]
 [1376.]
 [1967.]
 [2414.]
 [2012.]
 [2348.]
 [2293.]
 [1800.]
 [2011.]
 [2340.]
 [1949.]
 [2015.]
 [2338.]
 [1866.]
 [1461.]
 [2158.]]
```

Comment: thanks akdev. However, this does not solve the issue, I still get "400 Bad Request", maybe I am missing something in the request.post part? request context maybe? I am struggling to make it work :)

Comment: could you please provide more complete code? I've tested it (flask part, not numpy) and it worked. also can you please check out if `jsondata = request.get_json(force=True)` receives correct data? `print(jsondata)` after this line and check output in console

Comment: I edited the code above, just to return the data from jsondata... which is
{    "w0": 16671.0,
    "w1": 10335.0,
    "w2": 14398.0,
    "w3": 17589.0,
    "w4": 14658.0,
    "w5": 17129.0,
    "w6": 16729.0,
    "w7": 13267.0,
    "w8": 14677.0,
    "w9": 16970.0,
    "w10": 14242.0,
    "w11": 14613.0,
    "w12": 17002.0,
    "w13": 13621.0,
    "w14": 10745.0,
    "w15": 15659.0
}

Comment: when running the request.post line I get the "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem."

Comment: The error typically means you are trying to execute your function (`def predict()`) outside flask environment. Do you run `app.run()` in your app? If yes, you should be given address (usually `http://127.0.0.1:5000`). And then you should send your request `r = request.post(url, json = jsondata)` with `url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api"` from another script

Comment: I understand, this is what I was doing (sorry for not sending earlier - I updated the request script)

Comment: I see, you need to split up your code to 2 separate files: one for webserver (flask), the second one for the rest part (getting data from .txt file, sending it by `requests.post()`), and launch them apart.

Comment: The are 2 different scripts already, the first is main.py (request.post) and the flask in server.py. That's why I do not see/understand the errors so far! thank you for your time!

Comment: does the above work for you?

Comment: I could check everything except for `numpy` part as soon as I don't have your data file and it woked. Which error do you receive now? Could you please provide full traceback?

Comment: File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)
File "/home/flask_milk/main.py", line 26, in <module>
r = request.post(url, json = jsondata)
File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

Comment: *.dat file contains:  "2297   0   0.513
   1376   0   0.502
   1967   0   0.505
   2414   0   0.530
   2012   0   0.509
   2348   0   0.513
   2293   0   0.505
   1800   0   0.491
   2011   0   0.498
   2340   0   0.508
   1949   0   0.494
   2015   0   0.513
   2338   0   0.536
   1866   0   0.514
   1461   0   0.504
   2158   0   0.512"  i.e. 3 columns (the first is the only I need to pass)

Comment: I have updated my answer, now it's complete example which I had tested - please try it and tell me if it helps